# Diferencias entre methods y comand en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a estudiar JavaScript, pero en varios libros y consultas web aparecen los términos *methods* y *commands*, pero por lo que veo ambos utilizan `()` y realizan la misma acción.

Por ejemplo, esto es un comand:

```
var name = "Ejemplo"; alert("Hello " + name);
```

y es un method:

```
var name ="Ejemplo"; name.toUpperCase();
```

¿Me podrían decir cuál es la diferencia entre ambos por favor?

Comment: Cuando hablas de commands, te refieres a que exactamente??? a comandos de consola???

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir algún ejemplo de código o cita del libro? No está claro a que te refieres con commands.

Comment: var name = "Ejemplo"; alert("Hello " + name); esto es un comand

Comment: var name ="Ejemplo"; name.toUpperCase(); es un method

Comment: Lo que no me queda claro es cual es la diferencia entre ambos ya que los 2  utilizan () y a los 2 se les puede poner Syntax dentro del paréntesis.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que botes ese libro o página y busques uno mejor. Ambos son funciones, en el segundo caso se llama método porque le pertenece a un objeto en este caso al string `name`

Comment: Polo, es mejor [edit] tu pregunta para añadir ese tipo de detalles que escribes aqui en los comentários. Luego notificas a la persona con un arroba `@UserName, pregunta actualizada`. Saludos y bienvenido al site!

Comment: Por qué dices que ambos realizan la misma acción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno no se que tan acertada será mi respuesta, pero este es mi granito de arena para aclarar un poco tu confusión y tratar de direccionarte mejor.

Así como tu dices, ambos utilizan los paréntesis (). En este caso lo que va dentro de los paréntesis  representan los argumentos, o dicho de otra forma los datos de entrada. Estos datos de entradas son procesados y arrojan un resultado. Imagínate una caja negra donde le arrojas cosas, que transforma lo que recibe y arroja algo nuevo.

¿Cuál es el proceso que esta ocurriendo detrás de bambalinas? bueno por ahora simplemente puedes ignorarlo. En este momento no nos interesa mucho como se logra eso, sino simplemente el resultado final.

Por ejemplo, con `alert("Hola mundo")` lo que sucede es que le ingresas el texto: "Hola mundo" y el resultado será que te muestra una pequeña ventana de alerta con ese mismo mensaje que le ingresaste.

Por otro lado, si tienes una variable `name = "polo"` y ejecutas `name.toUpperCase()`, lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

1. Como no hay nada dentro de los paréntesis, quiere decir que no ingresaste datos de entrada.
2. Entonces la duda es ¿Qué es lo que voy a transformar si no ingrese nada?
   En este caso, si observas después de `name` hay un punto. Este punto esta conectando `toUpperCase()` a `name` y se intuye que existe un relación entre los dos.
3. ¿Cuál es esa relación? bueno es simple, `toUpperCase()` traduce a "convertir a mayúsculas", se podría suponer que esta operación convertirá en mayúsculas lo que esta antes del punto. Y es así, si corres `name.toUpperCase()` obtendrás que `polo` se convierte en `POLO`.

Ya desglosado esto un poco, te mencionare dos nuevos términos: función y método.

Una función es un bloque de código diseñado para ejecutar una tarea particular, por ejemplo `alert`. A lo que tu le estabas llamando *command*. Una función recibe unos argumentos, los transforma y arroja un resultado.

Por otro lado, un método es una función dentro de un objeto. Esto quiere decir que los datos de entrada los extrae del mismo objeto del cual proviene. Por ejemplo con `name.toUpperCase()` el objeto es `name`. `name` es una cadena de texto que tiene un método `toUpperCase`, el cual lo transforma cambiándolo a mayúsculas. Es decir, no necesita argumentos porque los datos de entrada los sacó del mismo objeto.

Sin embargo, hay veces que necesitas más información para poder lograr que la función haga lo que tu quieres que haga, y esta información no la puede simplemente inferir del objeto.

Por ejemplo, el metodo `repeat(count)` necesita que se le defina la cantidad de veces que se va a repetir la cadena con la que se esta trabajando:

```
'abc'.repeat(0);    // ''
'abc'.repeat(1);    // 'abc'
'abc'.repeat(2);    // 'abcabc'
```